# Error: Cannot find module '/Users/users/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.5.0.cjs'

Tags: node.js, yarn-v2

My computer runs on macOS system.  I installed node 16.5+ version using nvm tool and installed yarn using npm, with version 1.22.7.  Today, I upgraded using the command "yarn set version berry".  However, my project reported an error and I tried to revert to the original version.

I uninstalled yarn using npm and deleted .yarn and yarnpack files, but the error still persists.  What should I do now?

Please help me.

```
users@usersMacBook-Pro ~ % yarn -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/users/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.5.0.cjs'
at Function.Module.   _resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
at Function.Module.   _load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
at Function.   executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
```

I uninstalled yarn using npm and deleted .yarn and yarnpack files, but the error still persists. What should I do now?

Comment: Maybe in `package.json` there is some reference to old yarn version?